# Xcode: If you register new device, which used a backup from the old device for restoration

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

If you register new device, which used a backup from the old device for restoration, make sure Provisioning Profile is well recognized.

In my case, Xcode identified my new iPhone to be usable for development, but couldn't recognize the Provisioning Profile in the device, thus failed to debug run.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution, I installed Provisioning Profiles manually.

In the linked page, "Removing an iOS device from the Scheme menu" is described.
However, if you evaluate the condition of profiles in the device using "Show Provisioning Profiles...", you can see + and - buttons for add/remove provisioning files.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/LaunchingYourApponDevices/LaunchingYourApponDevices.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH27-SW12

By adding the profiles manually in this way,
I could able to make sure Xcode to recognize my device to be usable for development.